# NameError: undefined local variable or method `request' for main:Object trying to make basic HttpAuth request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make basic HttpAuthentication request
I type `rails c`
And type:

```
env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(user,pw)
```

And I get an error
`NameError: undefined local variable or method`env' for main:Object
`

Comment: Type `env` in capitals `ENV`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Deep said in the comment, try changing `env` to `ENV`.